# Which of the two peripheral Barcelona airports (Girona or Reus) has the cheapest connection to the city?

Tags: budget, airport-transfer, barcelona, gro, reu

There are flights from Frankfurt Hahn Airport (HHN) to both Girona-Costa Brava Airport (GRO) and Reus Airport (REU). The flight prices are similar, so I am wondering which airport has the cheapest connection to Barcelona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.reus-tourist-guide.com/en/airport/reus-airport-to-barcelona.html#reusAirportBarcelonaBus) there's a bus from Reus Airport to Barcelona:

> The journey time is one and a half hours, and it costs **€12.50** for a single ticket and €22.00 for a return. The bus travels to Barcelona Sants bus station.

A [similar site](http://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/gerona/girona-airport-barcelona.html#barcelonabus) states the following about the bus from Girona Airport to Barcelona:

> Tickets cannot be reserved in advance and cost **€15.00** for a single and €25.00 for a return.

Comment: For completeness, the bus from Barcelona airport (BCN) is €5.75 if you catch the Airport bus, or €2.00 if you catch the regular city bus (or even less if you use a T10 card which will give you 10 trips on most local buses/metro/etc for under €10)

Comment: I'd also recommend T10 card as well. It's valid for the train from the airport to Barcelona and also within Barcelona.

Comment: @toy I missed any information about the train, feel free to leave an answer involving it.